# usb rubber ducky special characters

Tags: usb, rubber, duckyscript

Is there a way to let your usb rubber ducky know to type special characters like "ü, ö, ä or ß"? Because when I try to compile a rubber ducky script like for example:

```
REM My Rubber Ducky Script
STRING ß
```

Then the compiler will give me an error

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can but it is dependent upon your operating system what keyboard combinations output these special characters.

On OSX for example you could achieve `STRING ß` by accessing the Alt+S keyboard shortcut:

```
ALT s
ESC
REM escape used to confirm the special character
```

This is a little buggy to use in practice from my tests. It is possible that the keyboard character on a native german keyboard has a different assignment or character value that can be used that directly produces an eszett but I cant confirm this.